# Convert JS sprintf to Typescript equivalent

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking for a sort of 'sprintf' function for Javascript, I found this little function that is both simple and does what I want:

```
function sprintf(format) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var i = 0;
    return format.replace(/%s/g, function() {
        return args[i++];
    });
}
```

(Original source: https://gist.github.com/rmariuzzo/8761698)

The problem is that I want to use this function in an Angular 4 application, written in Typescript, so I can't call it because the compiler complains that the number of parameters doesn't match the required by the function.

I know that there are Typescript equivalents (f.i. https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) but require to install a module with npm and are way more complex than what I need.

I've never used multiple parameter functions in Typescript (besides the use of '?' on optional parameters) so I don't know how to adapt this function to be used in an Angular app.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript code is TypeScript code. It cannot be converted to that which it already is.

Comment: I know that Typescript transpiles to Javascript, but also is more strict, isn't it? When I try to call `this.sprintf("¿Delete object %s (%s)?", objId, objName);` the compiler gives an error ''Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target". How could I call it in the right way?

Comment: You can either annotate the type of the argument, e.g. `function sprintf(...format: any[])`, or just ignore the error. TypeScript emits code regardless of type checking errors. All JavaScript is TypeScript code. Having said that, why in the world would you want to use such a nasty function?

Comment: I couldn't compile the app, it was always complaining about the parameter mismatch. About why I want to use such a function: I come from PHP and I've been using its '`sprintf`' function for ages. Do you use something similar in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function sprintf(format, ...args) {
    var i = 0;
    return format.replace(/%s/g, function() {
        return args[i++];
    });
}
```